# Visualize intersection of dataframes in table or matrix

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, data-visualization, intersection

I have three dataframes, and I want to visualize the intersection between each other.

Say I have three dataframes as shown below:

```
length(df1) 
length(df2) 
length(df3) 

[1] 283
[1] 290
[1] 295
```

I can currently show the intersection between the different sets by using `intersect()`

```
length(intersect(df1, df2)
length(intersect(df1, df3)
length(intersect(df2, df3)

[1] 96
[1] 227
[1] 98
```

While this gives me an answer, I'm working with RMarkdown and am looking for a way to make it easier to see the intersections. I may eventually work with more dataframes, and would like a solution that can scale up.

I was wondering if there was a way to display the intersection in a table or matrix, like shown:

```
    | df1 | df2 | df3 |
----|-----|-----|-----|
df1 | 283 |  96 | 227 |
df2 |  96 | 290 |  98 |
df3 | 227 |  98 | 295 |
```

Is this possible? Even better, is there a solution that makes it look nice in RMD, or compatible with `knitr::kable`?

Comment: How are you doing `intersect(df1,df2)` on two data.frames, or for that matter using `length()` against a `data.frame` to count rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be a package to do this, but it is also easy to construct on your own:

Given your numbers:

```
#your values
upper_lower <- c(96, 227, 98)
diagonal <- c(283, 290, 295)

#constructing the matrix
#make empty matrix
mat <- matrix(NA, ncol=3, nrow=3)
#add the values to the lower and upper matrix
mat[upper.tri(mat)] <- mat[lower.tri(mat)] <- upper_lower
#add the diagonal
diag(mat) <- diagonal
#give the names
colnames(mat) <- c('df1', 'df2', 'df3')
rownames(mat) <- c('df1', 'df2', 'df3')
```

Result:

```
mat
#    df1 df2 df3
#df1 283  96 227
#df2  96 290  98
#df3 227  98 295
```

Comment: This is perfect! I can throw the matrix into `kable` as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Putting aside my comment for a moment, you should be able to use `?outer` to generate your desired matrix output semi-automatically. Take these 3 vectors as an example:

```
v1 <- 1:8
v2 <- 4:9
v3 <- 6:12

ldf <- mget(c("v1","v2","v3"))
outer(ldf, ldf, FUN=function(x,y) lengths(Vectorize(intersect)(x,y)))
#   v1 v2 v3
#v1  8  5  3
#v2  5  6  4
#v3  3  4  7
```